# How to install django?

Tags: python

I have installed python 2.7 and ran the setup.py it executed various commands on command prompt but how can i see tha face of django i don't know what next step is. Whether i should have to set the path or not and how can i start the framework after setting the path. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Django's documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/) is really excellent. You should read it. Run through the tutorials.

Comment: Is this the first time you've installed (and used) Python? Django is a Python framework, so it might help you to familiarize yourself with Python before attempting to develop using Django, if you haven't done so already.

Answer (score 1):

For installing django you should use `python setup.py install`
After it if you're using Windows you should add `django-admin.py` to your system path. On Linux this is done automatically. (You may choose not to do this if you don't want, but then you have to specify path to `django-admin.py` everytime you use it.)

When you want to start some project, just go to the destination folder and run `django-admin.py startproject myprojectname` (or, probably `python django-admin.py startproject myprojectname` on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Consult these...

http://www.djangoproject.com/download/

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

..in that order. The first two links are installation guides, the third link is the first part of the "official" Django tutorial. It's pretty nifty, so I'd recommend you work through it.